# Html Agility Pack selecting subattributes

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

Hello i have some problems when i try to get subattributes
Example

```
<p attribute:subattribue="mytext">hello world<p>
```

I tried to do this:

```
textblock1.Text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p[@attribute:subattribute='mytext']").InnerText.Trim();
```

Sorry but I'm a Newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, in XPath you can use following expression to get `<p>` element having attribute name equals `attribute:subattribute` and the attribute value equals `mytext` :

```
//p[@*[name()='attribute:subattribute' and .='mytext']]
```

Unfortunately, above XPath doesn't work using HtmlAgilityPack (returned `null` when I tried). But there is a workaround, by using LINQ to query data with the same criteria as above XPath :

```
HtmlNode n = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//p")
                .Where(o => o.Attributes["attribute:subattribute"] != null && 
                            o.Attributes["attribute:subattribute"].Value == "myValue")
                .FirstOrDefault();
textblock1.Text = n.InnerText.Trim();
```